# Android load Text in TaskView with thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I have a Android app, with a Fragment Activity and a TextView with ID "debugLog".
I want to update the Textview every 500ms with new data.

My problem is, the Timer() works only once, and is then never executed?

```kotlin
class DiagnoseUart : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameterss
    val logWriter = LogWriter();

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diagnose_uart, container, false);
        val handler = Handler()
        val debugLog = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.debugLog);

        debugLog.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod();

        Timer().schedule(timerTask {
            val log = logWriter.getLog();
            this@DiagnoseUart.getActivity()?.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                debugLog.text = log;
            })
        }, 500);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help.
There are many more solutions for sure.

```
    var count = 1
    Timer().schedule(time = Date(), period = 500, action = {
        binding.textHome.text = count.toString()
        count += 1
    })
```

or

```
    var count = 1
    val timerHandler = Handler()
    val timerRunnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            binding.textHome.text = String.format("%d", count)
            count+=1
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500)
        }
    }
    timerRunnable.run()
```

or

```
     var count = 1

    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            //Call your function here
            binding.textHome.text = count.toString()
            count += 1
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500)//1 sec delay
        }
    }, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

this code works for me on API 23:

```
var count = 1
    Timer().schedule(time = Date(), period = 500, action = {
        binding.textHome.text = count.toString()
        count += 1
    })
```

and this:

```
val timerRunnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                val log = logWriter.getLog();
                this@DiagnoseUart.getActivity()?.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                    debugLog.text = log;
                })
                handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        }

        timerRunnable.run();
```

is the Timer automatically destroyed when my fragment view is closed?